# How to fix hairline crack in brick on exterior of house

Tags: repair, brick, masonry

I have a cracked brick outside my window, and it looks like the crack runs down the mortar to just under the window ledge.

The piece of the brick that cracked off is movable (ever so slightly) if I apply pressure, so it doesn't appear that the mortar on the top or bottom is adhered to it.

I can't, however, pull it out with my fingers, additionally the brick below it is immovable.

My main concern with this is water damage over time, getting into the crack or above/below it.

I suspect the most permanent solution is to remove the entire brick and and redo the mortar around it, tracing it down the crack.  However, I'd like a less costly and time-intensive solution, if possible.

I've looked into injecting (via syringe) some epoxy, however there's a lot of different products and I have no idea what to pick, if this is even a viable solution.

What is a good cost-effective way of dealing with this cracked brick?

[image: Cracked brick]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting epoxy is a viable solution. In this case there are not significant differences in various epoxies. Any should work.

A thicker/faster-curing epoxy might stay in the crack better, but those qualities also might make it stay in the syringe better too, so give that some thought.